# How to show in type theory (like in a proof assistant) that finite sets of different cardinalities are not isomorphic?

Tags: set-theory, proof-techniques

Disclaimer: this question is not asking for code -- it's asking for a proof strategy.

For simplicity we may use `Fin n` (for the usual `Fin` type like in Idris/Agda) for finite sets. I'm wondering what the best practice is to show that for $n\ne m$, it holds that $\text{Fin}~n\not\simeq\text{Fin}~m$ (i.e. there isn't a bijection). I can guess a proof that starts with:

> Suppose there is an isomorphism $\phi$. Also, w.l.o.g. we may assume $n<m$, then $\text{Fin}~m$ has more inhabitants.

Then, some distinct inhabitants of $\text{Fin}~m$ are sent to the same inhabitants of $\text{Fin}~n$, but how to show that?

In a math class, we draw pictures of sets and draw arrows to demonstrate the non-existence of bijections, but type theory wouldn't admit that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the Pigeonhole Principle. In a weak form it says that there is no injection from `Fin (n+1)` to `Fin n`. In a stronger form it says that if `f : Fin m -> Fin n` then there is some `i : Fin n` such that the fibre at `i` has cardinality at least `m / n`. The stronger form is perhaps more intuitive to prove but it requires more background machinery. For the weak form, proceed by induction on `n : Nat` to prove that for every `f : Fin (n+1) -> Fin n` there are `i j : Fin (n+1)` such that `i < j` and `f i = f j`.

The base case is trivial since `Fin 1` is inhabited while `Fin 0` is not.

For the induction step, given `f : Fin (n+2) -> Fin (n+1)`. We may assume that `f 0 = 0` otherwise compose with the involution that swaps `0` and `f 0`. Then consider these alternatives:

- If `f (i+1) > 0` for every `i : Fin (n+1)` then we have a function `f' : Fin (n+1) -> Fin n` such that `f (i+1) = (f' i) + 1` for all `i : Fin (n+1)`. Apply the induction hypothesis to `f'` and conclude.
- Otherwise `f (i+1) = 0` for some `i : Fin (n+1)`. Since `f 0 = 0` and `0 < i+1`, we conclude immediately.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially [the pigeonhole principle](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/master/Cubical/Data/Fin/Properties.agda#L436). If $m < n$, then $f : \mathsf{Fin}\ n → \mathsf{Fin}\ m$ takes two distinct values to the same value, meaning it cannot be an equivalence. This can then be used to prove that $\sf Fin$ is injective (simply by deciding trichotomy of $m$ and $n$; the above refutes the off-diagonal cases), which your proposition is the contrapositive of.

The linked proof is rather tricky, but that is mainly because the inductive step involves shrinking the function to a smaller example.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link!